# change type of fields in emf editor

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-emf

I'm using EMF to let the user create a model using a generated editor.
In the editor properties, in one of the properties of the model I want the user to click on "..." button instead of using string value. after he clicks the "..." button i will open a dialog that I created for him to pick from a list.
How do I change the property to show "..." instead of just being a string. Is it done in the ecore file?

Ido.

Answer (score 0):

In EMF, you can change the "look and feel" of your generated model editor in the .genmodel, in the Edit and / or Editor "plugin.properties" files or (for complicated and unusual things) by changing the generated code.

If you edit the generated code be careful to delete the "@generated" markers ... or your changes will DISAPPEAR next time you regenerate the code from your model!

In this case, I think you probably just need to change some plugin property strings.